# How to set up functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to Stack Overflow, so sorry if this is a bad format. I am not sure how to get this program up and running with multiple functions. I'm not asking for my homework to be done for me. I just would like to know how to call functions or if you can point me in the right direction to get this code running, thank you!

```
from datetime import datetime

mph = 0

def main():
    print("Arrival Time Estimator\n")


def get_departure_date(arrival_time):
    while True:
        date_str = input("Enter departure date (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
        try:
            departure_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again. ")
            continue

        if departure_date <= get_departure_time():
            print("Departure date must be after arrival date. " +
                  "Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return departure_date

def get_departure_time():
    while True:
        time_str = input("Enter departure time (HH:MM AM/PM): ")
        try:
            depart_time = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%H-%M %p")
        except ValueError: 
            print("Invalid date format. Try again.")
            continue

        now = datetime.now
        arrivaldate = get_departure_time() + (miles / mph)
        today = datetime(now.year, now.month, now.day)
        if depart_time < today:
            print("Arrival date must be today or later. Try again.")
            continue
        else:
            return arrival()

def arrival():
    miles = input("Enter miles:  ")
    mph = input("Enter miles per hour  ")
    arrivaldate = get_departure_time() + (miles / mph)
```

Comment: It seems that you need to work through a tutorial on calling Python functions, rather than a Stack Overflow posting.

Answer (score 2):

To call a python function, you use the name of the function. For instance, If your function is:

```
def arrival():
    miles = input("Enter miles:  ")
    mph = input("Enter miles per hour  ")
    arrivaldate = get_departure_time() + (miles / mph)
```

You can use it by calling

```
arrival()
```

Comment: You might want to use `print arrival()` so you can see the result.